# How can I get synonyms working in Datastax enterprise solr?

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

Am kicking the tires of the DSE SOLR implemenation.
Here is a schema snippet:

```
<!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for lowercase matching of words -->
<fieldType name="lowtokens" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<!-- ind name individual name synonyms on first token only (firstname) -->
<fieldType name="basename" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(^\S+)" group="1" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonym_ind.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(^\S+)" group="1" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and here is some rows from the synonyms file:

```
alan, al
alberta, berta, bertie, al, albie, bert, berto, burt
gregory, gre, greg, gregg, gregor, greig, grieg
```

So in Solr Analyser page, the Index does not expand Alan to Alan and Al
Same for Greg, etc.

GETing it from solr, it appears to be loaded ok:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/search.cust/synonym_ind.txt
synonym_ind.txt
```

It just returns the name instead of an error though. File is 38607 bytes in UNIX format.
Help?  Anyone using DSE SOLR?  Pity that Datastax shutdown their forums...

Answer (score 0):

- How did you upload the synonyms file?
- Did you force a Solr core reload after uploading the synonyms file?

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name="
```

- Did you upload synonyms and reload the Solr core before indexing documents, or did you force a DSE Solr reindex since your synonyms are index-time?

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name=&reindex=true&deleteAll=true"
```

- DataStax decided to switch from a proprietary support forum to SO, in theory to provide better support.

Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the response... Here is the order of events.